# mvc + WebApi SessionExpireAttribute is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Here i wrote SessionExpireAttribute as

```
public class SessionExpireAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
}
```

And i cal this Methode in my controller as

```
 [SessionExpireAttribute]
    public class IAuthController : ApiController{
 public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetServiceCall()
        {
}
```

But its not Hitting my Service please help me.. Here im having startup.cs fiile alos

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use it for `ApiController` then you need change type of parameter from `ActionExecutingContext` to `HttpActionContext`

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;

....

public class SessionExpireAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you soo much for your Feed back

Comment: Glad to have been of help